# How to Split compressed packets

Tags: c#, http, pcap, pcap.net

I write capture program. I use pcap.net and i capture live http requests on packets. I get token request and response body messages normally but when i try to get http api request's body part i get failed because my service header contains chunked and gzip content features. I need to split and combine to packages with ip protocol. I can not handle compressed byte array from pcap packet because packet is so complex. Please help us, i need to resolve pcap.net packets.

My http response body part return "ugur" normally.
"ugur" is equals to [117, 103, 117, 104] for byte array form.

When it compressed by gzip;
[31, 139, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 40, 43, 77, 47, 45, 2, 0, 180, 207, 126, 220, 4, 0 ,0 ,0] length of 24.

I can not handle this compressed 24 length byte array in pcap packet. how can i capture this byte array on fragments?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll first need to reconstruct the TCP stream.